# Why is my variable showing as null?

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-ui

I have this Html code but when i trying to execute in browser console i am getting error has

**elementWithHiddenContent is null**

My Html Code is:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>ControlShiftI Example</title>
<!-- <style>
input.password-input {
-webkit-text-security: disc;
}
</style>-->
<script>
var currentInnerHtml;
var element = new Image();
var elementWithHiddenContent = document.querySelector("#element-to-hide");
var innerHtml = elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML;

element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {
currentInnerHtml = "";
});

setInterval(function() {
currentInnerHtml = innerHtml;
console.log(element);
console.clear();
elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML = currentInnerHtml;
}, 1000);
</script>
</head> 

<body> 
<div id="element-to-hide"> 
Enter UserName <input name="user" type="text"><br> 
Enter Password <input class="password-input" name="pass" type="password"> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

Comment: `__defineGetter__` is deprecated, consider using something more standard

Answer (score 1):

Try moving your script to the bottom of the body. The element does not exist when the script executes.

Comment: Yes After moving bottom error is gone but it is not execute as I want Here that <div> tag need to disabled in browser inspector but it will showing their what can I do?

Comment: @ramanachollangi What exactly are you trying to do? Just hide the div?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the dom has not been loaded when you run the scriopt.
Put your code in a function and load it on the body load, this way you are sure that all your html has been rendered:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>ControlShiftI Example</title>
<!-- <style>
input.password-input {
-webkit-text-security: disc;
}
</style>-->
<script>
function bodyOnLoad() {
var currentInnerHtml;
var element = new Image();
var elementWithHiddenContent = document.querySelector("#element-to-hide");
var innerHtml = elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML;

element.__defineGetter__("id", function() {
currentInnerHtml = "";
});

setInterval(function() {
currentInnerHtml = innerHtml;
console.log(element);
console.clear();
elementWithHiddenContent.innerHTML = currentInnerHtml;
}, 1000);
}
</script>
</head> 

<body onload="bodyOnLoad()"> 
<div id="element-to-hide"> 
Enter UserName <input name="user" type="text"><br> 
Enter Password <input class="password-input" name="pass" type="password"> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No My Problem is when I do ctrl+_shift+i means inspect at that time i want  to disabled that <body> tag inside what content is their I don't want to show in browser inspector please any help?

Comment: @ramanachollangi Not possible.  You cannot disable the display of a tag in the user's browser if they pull up the debugger.  In order for the user to see any content, you have to send it.  So at the browser, you are at the mercy of the user.  But <body> is required, and it's required that the user can inspect all elements.  AFAIK, it's not possible to disable the debugger.  Ask Facebook, they've been trying for years to disable the JavaScript console due to security issues without success.